# What does ServiceStack MVC Power Pack give me that is not in the base ServiceStack library?

Tags: servicestack

What does ServiceStack MVC Power Pack give me that is not in the base SS library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have check [power pack link](http://servicestack.net/mvc-powerpack/). Basically this is what I like about service stack that everything comes in Lego pieces, so you can play plug things. Now, service stack is basically web service library which you can use with any json serializer or any IOC container with any orm. But if you install power pack it will give you everything to get up and started. Without worrying about choosing libraries, something like yak shaving is done for you; so you can concentrate on business need. Personally I prefer to check other things / options too other than provided by power pack but for normal case (80% scenario) power pack worked like charm. And get your application running.

Let me know if any further information needed. I hope I understand your question, so instead of dll names I gave little bit a brief answer.

[Service stack](http://vimeo.com/55817065) introduction at monkey square.

Comment: Ok thanks, what I really liked about what I read about the PowerPack was the ISession replacement and caching but I was planning to use my own ORM, in there, so I guess will have to experiment and see how it goes.

Comment: @OutOFTouch Yeah. For that you have to check it out which one is better. But I recommended Servicestack Ormlite. Its quite mature and nice one. And for that ISession, it is a custom implementation session. And for Caching again there are couple of option in SS only. I recommended monkey square video of SS by demis bellot, who started SS. It will help a lot. I have update my answer with link.